# Why not using Convolutional pooling instead of MaxPooling to avoid invariance

Tags: neural-networks, convolution, pooling

I was reading the paper of [Geoffrey Hinton: Capsule network], and I watch it's talk on Youtube about the problem of Conv Network is actually the (max) pooling layer, since we don't want to be invariant to transformations, for the reasons that he explains in the paper.

However, I see a simpler solution, that is (obviously) not using MaxPooling.
As an alternative, we can use a convolutional layer with the same number of filters as the input channels, and with a convolution size and a stride size as big as the MaxPooling layer.

I've implemented it in Tensorflow:

```py
class ConvPooling(K.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, pool_size, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pool_size = pool_size

    def build(self, input_shape):
        print(input_shape)
        assert input_shape[1] % self.pool_size[0] == 0 and input_shape[2] % self.pool_size[1] == 0
        self.filters = self.add_weight(name="filters", shape=(*self.pool_size, input_shape[3],input_shape[3]))

    def call(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):
        return tf.nn.selu(tf.nn.conv2d(inputs, self.filters, strides=self.pool_size, padding="VALID"))
```

And it works just fine, and if a run a AlexNet-like network with the maxpooling swapped with this, I get better results (tested on Fashon-MNIST)

My question is, doesn't this solves the problem of being invariant?
Since Convolution is equivariant to translation, and I'm only using convolution layer, so the equivariance property propagates layer to layer

Comment: Nice question Aberto! I have the same question as well. Except from the parameter-free downsampling maxpooling provides, I can't think another reason.

Comment: @adosar unfortunately got no answer, i can only think that it's done only to force some inductive bias

Comment: That is what I am also thinking. Picking the "maximum", i.e. the sharpest feature from a region. Of course, convolution + non-linearity can learn the "max" function but I would expect that more training data would be needed to learn it.